# Clicking on an Object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have the map in my game split into different areas. Each are made into a separate array in the Area array. I am currently stuck on being able to click on the object. When the player clicks on the object in the game the part of the map that he clicks on should pop up a certain amount and when he clicks on another part that part should pop up and the other one should do back to its original position. I am currently having that object be destroyed when I click on it, but it won't even be selected in game.

```
using UnityEngine;   
using System.Collections;

public class AreaSelection : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject[] Areas;

void Start()
{
    Areas = new GameObject[20];
}
void Update()
{
}
void OnMouseDown()
{
    Destroy(this.gameObject);
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with GameObject array Areas? Since it's a public variable it's going to be serialized and I'm guessing you're going to put your other Areas there. You don't need to initialize it (Areas = new GameObject[20];). Also, is every Area going to contain all the other Areas? For what purpose? Is it not better that there is some kind of AreaManager that controls & contains all the areas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "OnMouseDown is called when the user has pressed the mouse button while over the GUIElement or Collider."

-- [Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html)

This means that you need a Collider on the GameObject that this script is attached to. The OnMouseDown will only trigger on the GameObject it's attached to. So if you have this script on some kind of manager that doesn't have a Collider or size or anything, you won't be able to use OnMouseDown. If you'd like to go another route, which I sort of recommend, you'd relocate the logic to the `Update()` method sort of like this:

(from a 2d-project of mine)
```

```
RaycastHit2D hit;
public LayerMask mask;
Vector2 mousePos;
GameObject selectedObject;


void Update() {

    // If mouse left click is pressed
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
        mousePos = (Vector2)Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        hit = Physics2D.Raycast(mousePos, Vector2.zero, mask);

        if (hit.collider != null)
        {
            selectedObject = hit.collider.gameObject;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you have to set the public LayerMask in the inspector to only hit the Objects you want to hit.

With this script you should be able to send a Raycast from your screen towards your mouse and, if it hits any GameObject with the selected Layer in the LayerMask it will put that object in SelectedObject (and once you have the gameobject you can do whatever you want with it).

Comment: Would I have to put a Collider on each object or, if I had a gameobject that had all the map-objects in it, like a folder, would i be able to just put in on that object and be done.

Comment: @MadushaSilva obviously if you put a collider on an object only scripts attached to that object receives the OnMouseDown event

Comment: I updated the answer with a more extensive and practical example of an idea to do it.